# Can you change the default Apple Watch watch?

Tags: ios, iphone, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm planning to make an watch app for the `Apple Watch`.

Is there any way of replacing the default **home screen** (or watch) of the device to be a custom watch?

Assuming there is none, the next best way would be to make a `WatchKit App` complete with with a `Glance`?

Does the apple watch come with a **power saving mode** by default where it will turn off the screen/running app reverting to it's home screen after a certain period of inactivity?

Comment: No. https://devforums.apple.com/thread/254629?tstart=15

Answer (score 0):

There is not at present any way to have a custom watch face. You could make an app with a glance view, but just to be clear a glance view cannot contain any buttons or interactive elements, it's just something to be looked at. If the user taps the glance it will open your watch app.